# How can I include my --net=host in my Dockerfile before I deploy my container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a beginner to Docker and networking concepts. I have a dockerized application in my virtualbox. I am connecting to MySQL in another computer.

I was able to connect to it, then I was able to view the app, from my virtualbox using the `--net=host` option. From what I understand, this option maps both the docker and virtualbox machine's networks, and that is why I was able to see it in the browser in my virtualbox.

Should I be changing anything in my Dockerfile to make sure the connections work? How would I test it out after deployment whether or not this works? My current Dockerfile contains just RUN commands to install the necessary software.

My confusion arises like this. If say I deploy this (Azure) (beginner to deployment also), what port/address should I map/expose to make sure the app works after deployment also? Currently it is a flask app which is running on `127.0.0.1` address. But should I be changing anything in the Dockerfile?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.3

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y gcc g++ gfortran git patch wget && \
    apt install -y vim-tiny && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    cd / && \
    wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz && \
    cd redis-5.0.5 && \
    make && \
#    make test && \
    cd / && \
    rm redis-5.0.5.tar.gz && \
    cd / && \
    wget https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.12.13.tgz && \
    tar xvzf Ipopt-3.12.13.tgz && \
    cd Ipopt-3.12.13/ThirdParty/Blas/ && \
    ./get.Blas && \
    cd ../Lapack && \
    ./get.Lapack && \
    cd ../Mumps && \
    ./get.Mumps && \
    cd ../Metis && \
    ./get.Metis && \
    cd ../../ && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    ../configure && \
    make -j 4 && \
    make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm Ipopt-3.12.13.tgz
```

Currently I run

```
sudo docker run -it --net=host 5h71 /bin/bash
python app.py # inside the container

### which gives
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 052-293-642
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 671-290-156
```

Then I access `127.0.0.1:8050` to access the app on my chrome.

Comment: Post a copy of your Dockerfile(?).

Comment: @masseyb I have added it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your first question:

> How can I include my --net=host in my Dockerfile before I deploy my container?

You can't.  Runtime options that impact your host (such as network attachments, volume mounting, etc) cannot be included in your Dockerfile. This is a security restriction: if I could trick you into running an image that somehow ran with `--net=host` by default, I could do all sorts of nasty things.

If you have an application that requires options like that in order to be useful, and you get tired of typing long `docker run` command lines (or you want it to be easier for someone else to use) you can use a tool like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and create a `docker-compose.yml` that specifies all the appropriate runtime options.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. So my question now is, say I deploy it somewhere in azure, what would I be doing to access the `127.0.0.1` from the browser? Currently I accessed `127.0.0.1` from my browser after running the `app.py` from the docker container.